# Why two asterisks while accessing an element of 2-D array using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

In C, when we access `a[i][j]` using pointers why do we need the second `*` in `*(*(a + i) + j)`? Using `printf()` I see `a + i` and `*(a + i)` print the same value.

Comment: That statement about printf is incorrect, I think.

Comment: The above comment was for [mathepic](http://stackoverflow.com/users/205756/mathepic).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`a + i` is a pointer to the `i`'th subarray. If you dereference it, you get an lvalue to the `i`'th subarray, which decays to a pointer to that array's first element. The address of an array's first element and that of its array is the same.

The dereference is needed to make `+ j` calculate with the correct element byte-width. If you would not dereference, then instead of getting `T*` you would get a `T(*)[J]` pointer that you add `j` to, which together with `i` advances into memory pointing to `(a + i + j)` instead (advancing by `sizeof(T[J])` instead of `sizeof(T)`).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this requires a bit of pointer theory.

Lets assume we have

```
int** a = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 10);
int** p;
for(p = a; p < a + 10; p++) {
     *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 15);
}
```

This creates a 10 by 15 "array" implemented using pointers. Notice how each elements contained in the block of memory pointed to by `a` is of type `int*` (because we are mallocing a block of 15 `int`s).

Heres an incomplete diagram:

```
a
|
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 8 - 9 - 10
|   |
|   1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 - 12 - 13 - 14 - 15
|
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 - 12 - 13 - 14 - 15
```

So the main pointer is a pointer to a block that contains a bunch of pointers. So you end up dereferencing to get the inner pointer, you add to get another pointer, and you dereference again.

Answer (score 0):

2D arrays are like array of arrays. *(a+i) gives you the address of the one dimensional array that is at location i from the start address. Now you need the element at location j in this array. Hence you add j to it & then de-reference using * to access that element.